# Remove marker in google_maps_flutter

Tags: google-maps, flutter, google-maps-markers

I have added [Google Maps for Flutter](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/google_maps_flutter) 
i know how to add a marker as it is given clearly in there examples

```
MarkerOptions _options = new MarkerOptions(
          position: LatLng(
            driver_lat,
            driver_lng,
          ),
          infoWindowText:
              const InfoWindowText('An interesting location', '*'));

      Marker marker = new Marker('1', _options);

      //Adding Marker
      googleMapController.addMarker(_options);
```

And i am removing the marker like below

```
googleMapController.removeMarker(marker);
```

for adding the marker it is taking MarkerOptions object as a parameter but for removing the marker it is asking for Marker object as parameter and my removing marker code is not working.
i am getting the below error

```
Failed assertion: line 201 pos 12: '_markers[marker._id] == marker': is not true.
```

Comment: Could you please share your all error line and whole code block that you use for removing? And can you be sure that marker is not null at that moment? Because in this example, it looks pretty straightforward https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/a6a469a0da9e90b83d957c2c612a994ff1c73adc/packages/google_maps_flutter/example/lib/place_marker.dart

Comment: Same error here when trying this `googleMapController.removeMarker(marker);`

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to do this, one is via `clearMarkers()` Method

```
mapController.clearMarkers();
```

Another one is via targeting each marker returned by `mapController.markers`

```
mapController.markers.forEach((marker){
      mapController.removeMarker(marker);
});
```

Comment: There's no such method in v2

Answer (score 3):

2020 answer:

.clearMarkers() has been deprecated as now each Marker is a Widget stored in a map. The correct way to clear all of the markers now on your Google Map is to set the state of of your marker Map to an empty map.

e.g.

```
                ...
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      gMapMarkers = {};
                    });
                  }
                ....
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `clearMarkers()`. It will clear all markers in your map. So try `googleMapController.clearMarkers();`

Answer (score 0):

I've came across this issue myself with the `google_maps_library` and the main cause of this issue `'_markers[marker._id] == marker': is not true.` is the fact that all `GoogleMapsController` methods return a `Future`, so this error is, let's say a concurrency issue since the method cals are `async`.

The correct way to add/remove a marker would be:

```
_testRemoveMarker() async {
    Marker marker = await _mapController.addMarker(...markerOption..);
    _mapController.removeMarker(marker);
} 

_clearMarkersAndRead() async {
   _mapController.clearMarkers().then((_) {
       //TODO: add makrers as you whish;
   });
}
```

So, if you do any operations with the markers add/remove/update, you should be sure that the previous operation that involved markers is completed.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still struggling with removing a specific marker try this method;

```
      MarkerId id = MarkerId("Pickup");
      //markers[id] = {} as Marker; clear all markers
      markers.removeWhere((key, value) => key == id); //clear a specific marker
```