# Flutter - How to remove a marker in google maps?

Tags: google-maps, flutter, marker

I want to be able to remove markers through the modal, I've tried `clearMarkers()` and `removeMarkers()` but they don't seem to work anymore.

I also tried this one

> [Flutter - How to remove an individual google_maps_flutter ^0.5.21 marker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57922281/flutter-how-to-remove-an-individual-google-maps-flutter-0-5-21-marker)

but when I click remove marker It gives me: `Bad state: No element`

```
  _handleTap(LatLng point) async {
    if (_markers.isEmpty) {
      FirebaseUser users = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
      Firestore.instance
          .collection("markers")
          .document(users.uid)
          .setData({
        "coordinates": point.toString(),
      });
      setState(() {
        _markers.add(Marker(
          markerId: MarkerId(point.toString()),
          position: point,
          onTap: () {
            showModalBottomSheet<void>(
                context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return Container(
                child: new Wrap(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new ListTile(
                        leading: new Icon(Icons.delete),
                        title: new Text('Remove marker'),
                        onTap: () =>
                        {
                           _markers.remove(_markers.firstWhere((Marker marker) => marker.markerId.value == point))
                        }
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            });
          },
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call this setState() after _markers.remove().

```
_handleTap(LatLng point) async {
    if (_markers.isEmpty) {
      FirebaseUser users = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
      Firestore.instance
          .collection("markers")
          .document(users.uid)
          .setData({
        "coordinates": point.toString(),
      });
      setState(() {
        _markers.add(Marker(
          markerId: MarkerId(point.toString()),
          position: point,
          onTap: () {
            showModalBottomSheet<void>(
                context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return Container(
                child: new Wrap(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new ListTile(
                        leading: new Icon(Icons.delete),
                        title: new Text('Remove marker'),
                        onTap: () =>
                        {
                           _markers.remove(_markers.firstWhere((Marker marker) => marker.markerId.value == point))
                        }
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            });
          },
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, I did try to but setState() after _markers.remove(), but It didn't seem to make a difference and I got the same error also the code that you answered with is exactly the same as mine.

Answer (score 0):

This way works for me;

```
  MarkerId id = MarkerId("Pickup");
  //markers[id] = {} as Marker; clear all markers
  markers.removeWhere((key, value) => key == id); //clear a specific marker
```