# Flutter hide a googlemap marker

Tags: flutter, google-maps-markers

In a flutter application displaying a Google map, how do you hide a marker by clicking on it?
Thank you for your answers.

YC

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove marker in google\_maps\_flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53132358/remove-marker-in-google-maps-flutter)

Comment: No, I don't want to remove it, I just want to make it invisible so that I can put it back visible at the click of a button.

Comment: see this https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/e714f1b80d95918becd708d629d54a7d1951daa5/packages/google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter/example/lib/place_marker.dart#L243