# Cannot clear map marker with Animarker Solve : The method 'clearMarkers' isn't defined for the type 'Completer'?

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello i'am using Animarker package (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_animarker) and I cannot clear map markers using it, it is a big problem .

I end up with marker adding each time, carousel list is scrolled, by the user instead of only showing marker one by one.

I have to set the controller like this :

```
late final Completer<GoogleMapController> _mapController = Completer();
```

in order to use futur in mapId required Animaker element

```
Animarker(
          mapId: _mapController.future.then<int>((value) => value.mapId),
          rippleRadius: 0.6,  //[0,1.0] range, how big is the circle
          rippleColor: Colors.grey, // Color of fade ripple circle
          rippleDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 2500),
          markers:_storeMarkers.toSet(),
          runExpressAfter: 1,
```

I have tried solution from this but without success [Remove marker in google_maps_flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53132358/remove-marker-in-google-maps-flutter)

My call is that when this function is called it is clearing the map and then add the new marker

```
void _carouselCallback(Product product)  {
    var fe= product.store?.id;
   // _mapController.clearMarkers();
    //_storeMarkers.remove(_storeMarkers.firstWhere((Marker marker) => marker.markerId.value == '3'));

    _storeMarkers.clear();
    final marker=    RippleMarker(
      markerId: MarkerId('${product.store?.id}'),
      alpha: 1,
      icon: _storePin ?? BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
      position: LatLng(product.store?.lat ?? 0, product.store?.long ?? 0),
      ripple: false,
      onTap: () {
        if (product.store != null) {
          _carouselModePinCallback(product.store);

        }
      },
    );
    _storeMarkers.add(marker);
    _moveToStore(product.store);
    setState(() {});
  }
```

_storeMarker is a Set

Could someone help ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
markers[myMarkerId] = Marker(markerId: myMarkerId, visible: false);
```

and the problem will be solved.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hello thank you for your answers could you give a bit more information should it be passed in Googlemap widget , Animarker or _carouselCallback void function  ? thanks